# what is `firewalld --nofork`

Tags: fedora, firewalld

I carelessly killed the following process

```
root       470     1  0 Jun06 ?        00:00:13 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork
```

Is there any consequence from killing the process?

Are there any ways to restart it?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD

Comment: See my answer for how to restart the firewalld. I believe that's the correct method.

Answer (score 3):

Firewalld is a dynamic firewall service. You can read more about it here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD

*excerpt*

> firewalld provides a dynamically managed firewall with support for
>   network/firewall zones to define the trust level of network
>   connections or interfaces. It has support for IPv4, IPv6 firewall
>   settings and for ethernet bridges and has a separation of runtime and
>   permanent configuration options. It also supports an interface for
>   services or applications to add firewall rules directly.

Applications, daemons and the user can request to enable a firewall feature over D-BUS through this daemon, so in general you should be OK, but you'll eventually want to restart it.

To restart it you'll most likely do this command:

```
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

`firewalld` is a firewall daemon that maintains your personal machine's firewall. The `--nofork` flag means that the daemon does not fork a child process when it is started up. If you kill this process, you also kill your personal firewall, which may not have any effect if you never configured a firewall to begin with using `firewall-cmd` or `firewall-config`. More information:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD

Comment: how to restart it?

Comment: `sudo service firewalld start` if it is not already running and `sudo service firewalld restart` if it is.